# kinldy explain the meaning of this Dua 'Nahmaduhu Wa Nusalli Ala Rasoolilah Kareem~ Amma 'Baad

Tags: dua

Could you please give the translation of this dua that we recite before starting a talk:

```
'Nahmaduhu Wa Nusalli Ala Rasoolilah Kareem~
Amma 'Baad...
```

Also, is this Dua mentioned in hadith?

Jazakallah khair

Comment: I don't think this is the full quote of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Nahmaduhu - we give thanks (to Allah)

wa - and

nusalli - we send our greetings/praise

ala - upon

rasoolilah kareem - the noble Prophet (peace be upon him).

amma ba’ad - and following that,…